# UICollectionView always one item behind

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionViewController, created in a storyboard, and I have the delegate method 'didDeselectItemAtIndexPath'. However, when this method fires it always returns the indexPath from the previous touch. Ultimately, this means the first touch results in nothing happening.

Example:
- User touches cell 2, nothing happens
- User touches cell 5, cell 2 is returned
- User touches cell 3, cell 5 is returned

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is normal. You are using "didDeselectItemAtIndexPath". That means you chose something first then when you choose another thing it fires. You should use "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" and everything is gonna be fine.